# vista "network and sharing center" "the parameter is incorrect"

Tags: windows-vista, control-panel, windows-networking

On Vista Home Premium SP1, when I try:

- Start
- Control Panel
- network and sharing center
- File Sharing
- Turn On File Sharing
- Apply

I get a very windows 95-esque dialog that says "The parameter is incorrect." With an OK button.  No other explanation.  Any ideas on what I should do enable file sharing?  I get the same result if I try to turn on Network discovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the user account you are logged in with has a password on it.  If it doesn't, crate one and then restart (or at least log out and in again).  I had this exact problem with a Vista machine trying to enable Public Folder sharing and that is what finally fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks rymo -- I've upgraded all of my vista machines to Win7 -- so I can't test it. I'll all it answered though -- thanks!